# How to hightlighting php syntax error by Sublime Text 3?

Tags: php, sublimetext3

Sublime Text 2 had a PHP Syntax Error highlighting mechanism.

But I'm using Sublime Text 3 and I already searched for a PHP Syntax Error highlighter.

`SublimeLinter` and `node.js` aren't working.

And the Sublime Text Support had no solution.

I need a Sublime Text 3 Syntax Checker.

Comment: syntax checker just run `php -l file.php`. Check you have runnable cli php.

Answer (score 5):

Using Sublime Linter 3
The biggest change between this and other versions of Sublime Linter is that a new package must be installed for each of the languages that we need to lint.

follow this link: https://scotch.io/tutorials/how-to-catch-your-errors-in-sublime-text-3

Answer (score 3):

Sublime text 3 doesn't have built in PHP linting. Use the [Sublime Linter](http://www.sublimelinter.com/en/latest/) plugin and the [PHP linter](https://github.com/SublimeLinter/SublimeLinter-php).

Comment: Sublime Linter and PHP Linter not working too. This plugin work at sublime text 3?

Comment: Yes it works. Make sure you have the sublime text 3 version installed and the php binary available on your PATH.

Comment: Thanks for answer justin, I'll try check.